# jQuery Resizeable doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#box" ).resizable();
});

.container {
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #000;
}

#box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0.5em; 
}

<div class="container">
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

All I see is a red box, inside a black box, cannot see the resize icon at all like in the example here:

http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#helper

I looked at their css file, it seems like with the class `.ui-widget-content` it works, but why?

What makes that resize icon popup in there?
Why doesn't it work?

there:

```
<html>
<head id="html">
<title>Jquery project</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<div class="container">
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.container {
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #000;
}

#box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0.5em; 
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#box" ).resizable();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? You do have both jQuery and jQueryUI correctly linked right?

Comment: It works fine... make sure to add jquery script and jqueryui script... http://jsfiddle.net/HCZTx/

Comment: Doesn't for me, also no errors. Read my edit.

Comment: You're missing your `<body></body>` tags

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the jQuery UI stylesheet:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The entire jQuery UI project uses stylesheets to determine the look and feel of the widgets. The resizable icon is in the stylesheet:

```
.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se {
    background-position: -64px -224px;
}
.ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
}
```

The width and height of your element is controlled via styles. On the [jquery download page](http://jqueryui.com/download/), there is a section (at the bottom) to customize the look and feel. You're free to design your own; the one that I referenced is the default.

Comment: Why do I need to use their stylesheet though? while the JSFiddle above doesn't use it.

Comment: The JSFiddle does use it; inspect the iframe that has the result in it and you will see the script files and the stylesheet

Comment: What CSS exactly do I need to use for it to work? I don't really want to apply their styling into my design. What makes that icon appear?

Answer (score -1):

Just use this....

`#box { resize:both; }`

in css